# Rotate an object in the confinements of another object? (Paddle, Oar)

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, constraints, extrude

So in my case I have an oar and a brace, that the oar goes into. I want to animate the oar in a rowing motion. However every time I rotate the oar it goes out of the confinements of the brace. Is there any way to rotate the oar in a clockwise rotation without it going outside of the brace? The brace is basically just an extruded circle.

[image]

Comment: put the origin of the oar at the brace position, where the rotation center is supposed to happen, or parent the oar to an empty that is at the position of the brace. Also you can limit the rotation so that it doesn't go too far. But maybe show some pictures?

Comment: Would you mind explaining the steps you suggested above I'm new to blender, see I parented the oar to the brace. I've tried to find a way to get the child to move with the parent but have had 0 success.

Answer (score 12):

To make the animation you could first put the origin of the oar at its rotation center. Then create a *Curve > Circle* where the oar is supposed to point towards. Also create an empty that will rotate around this curve with a *Follow Path* constraint (keyframe the constraint *Offset* value). Give the oar a *Track To* constraint with the empty as *Target*. The oar will follow. If you want to duplicate the whole thing, parent everything to an empty, and duplicate.

[image]

To put the origin at the right position: Select the brace vertices in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*. Select the oar in *Object* mode and right click > *Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor*. Now the origin of the oar is where the rotation center is supposed to be.

The *Track To* settings:

[image]

You could also make an empty rotate around another empty but the movement will be always circular, while with a curve you'll be able to edit and change its shape if necessary:

[image]

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much for the help, really appreciate it!